# Difficult Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to write a formula which would allow to generate the 'Goal: Status' column below:

```
File Date    Frequency   Lag   Expected Date   Today's Date  Goal: Status   Current Formula
10/31/2020    1          15     12/15/2020      11/20/2020     Green          Green
9/30/2020     3          5      1/4/2021        11/20/2020     Green          Green
6/30/2020     3          15     9/15/2020       11/20/2020     Red            Red
9/30/2020     1          20     10/19/2020      11/20/2020     Yellow         Green
9/30/2020     1          30     11/30/2019      11/20/2020     Green          Green
9/30/2020     1          10     11/10/2019      11/20/2020     Yellow         Green
```

Here is the logic overall:

1. If the Frequency is 3 and the File Date is the same as the last quarter end, then Green.
2. If the Frequency is 1 and the File Date is the same as the last month end, then Green.
3. If the File Date is not as of last month or quarter end, use the Expect Date (File Date + Frequency + Lag) to see if Today's date is before that. If so, Green because we would not expect the next file until the Expected Date has passed.
4. If the File Date is not as of the last month or quarter end, if the Expected Date has passed by two or more months compared to Today's Date, then Red.
5. If the File Date is not as of the last month or quarter end, if the Expected Date has passed by less than two or more months compared to Today's Date, then Yellow.

Logic Line by Line:

1. Frequency is 1 and File Date is 10/31/2020 - Green
2. Frequency is 3 and File Date is 9/30/2020 - Green
3. File Date is not the same as last month end or quarter end, and the expect Date according to the Frequency of the next file was 9/15/2020. This is more than two months since Today's Date so Red.
4. Frequency is 1 and File Date is not as of last month end, Expected Date is less than two months since Today's Date so Yellow
5. Frequency is 1 but File Date is as of 9/30/2020 but Expect Date is past Today's Date, is before the Expected Date, so Green.
6. Frequency is 1 but File Date is as of 9/30/2020 and the Expect Date is less than two months before Today's Date so Yellow.

The current formula I have considers latest month and quarter end, but not frequency so it only works well for the first two lines:

```
=IF(A2=DATE(IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())>=1,MONTH(TODAY())<4),YEAR(TODAY())-1,YEAR(TODAY())),IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())>=1,MONTH(TODAY())<4),12,IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())>=4,MONTH(TODAY()*2)<7),3,IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())>=7,MONTH(TODAY())<10),6,9))),IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY())>=1,MONTH(TODAY())<7),31,30)),"Green",IF(A2=(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)),"Green","Red"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help. End of last month:

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)
```

And end of last quarter:

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-MOD(MONTH(TODAY())-1,3) -1)
```

*works by determining #month in current quarter 1, 2 or 3 and deducting that from the current date with EOMONTH. E.g. July would be 1 month to deduct and August 2 months to backdate to end June.

You can define those two formulas as names "lastmonth" and "lastquarter" with Formulas > Define Name

Now you can do direct date IF comparisons:

```
=IF(Frequency = 3, IF(date = lastquarter, "green", else...), IF(Frequency = 1, IF(date = lastmonth, "green", else...)
```

OR more compact

```
=IF(date = IF(Frequency = 1, lastmonth, lastquarter), "green",  IF(today < expected date, "green",  today < EDATE(expected date,2), "yellow", "red")
```